# What does minus 1 means in the method about calculating height of red-black tree?

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

I cannot understand why we should minus 1 in line 4.
I think just returning height(root) is fine, what does minus 1 mean?

```
public int height() {
    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    return height(root) - 1;
}

public int height(Node<K,V> node) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    int leftheight = height(node.left) + 1
    int rightheight = height(node.right) + 1
    if (leftheight > rightheight)
        return leftheight;
    return rightheight;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This minus one is necessary because the second `height` function does not calculate the height, but one more than the height.

The height of a tree is defined as the number of edges on the longest path from the root to a leaf, but the second function calculates the number of *nodes* (or *levels*) on the longest path from the root to a leaf, which is always one more.

I agree that this is a strange way of doing it, as actually it makes the name of the second function wrong: it doesn't do what it says.

Moreover, the main function has a problem too, because when the root is null, the height should return -1.

It is more natural to change the base case, and make the second function really return the height of the node that is passed as argument:

```java
public int height() {
    return height(root); // Simple: if no argument was passed, the default is the root
}

public int height(Node<K,V> node) {
    if (node == null)
        return -1; // <-----
    int leftheight = height(node.left) + 1
    int rightheight = height(node.right) + 1
    if (leftheight > rightheight)
        return leftheight;
    return rightheight;
}
```

It may be strange to have the value -1 there, but the reasoning is as follows:

This is a tree with height 1:

```
      a
     / \
    b   c
```

... because the longest path from the root has **one** edge; it is a tree with 2 levels, and the height is one less than the number of levels.

This is a tree with height 0:

```
      a
```

Here the number of levels is 1, and so the height is 0.

One step more, is an **empty** tree -- it doesn't even have a node, and zero levels, and so the corresponding height should be -1.

See also [What is the definition for the height of a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209777/what-is-the-definition-for-the-height-of-a-tree).

Comment: thanks so much! your description helped me really hard, and also your upgraded code is so understandable than original one. Also appreciate for the link you attached.